# FutureWarning: Automatic reindexing on DataFrame vs Series comparisons is deprecated and will raise ValueError in a future version

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, series

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:8: FutureWarning: Automatic reindexing on DataFrame vs Series comparisons is deprecated and will raise ValueError in a future version.  Do `left, right = left.align(right, axis=1, copy=False)` before e.g. `left == right`

I tried to remove outlier from my data frame
using z-score manually by me

```
numerical_cols=df.select_dtypes(['int64','float64'])
for col in numerical_cols:
    feature_value_less_than_3sigma=df[col].mean()-3*(df[col].std())
    feature_value_greater_than_3sigma=df[col].mean()+3*(df[col].std())
    df = df[~((df[col] < (feature_value_less_than_3sigma)) |(df[col] > (feature_value_greater_than_3sigma)))]
else:
    print('\nAfter: ',df.shape)
```

I don't know what this error is telling and I like to know about it ,Can anyone explain with some simple example

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of:**

```
df = df[~((df[col] < (feature_value_less_than_3sigma)) |(df[col] > (feature_value_greater_than_3sigma)))]
```

**Use:**

```
df = df.query('~(%s < @feature_value_less_than_3sigma or %s > @feature_value_greater_than_3sigma)' %(col,col))
```

This should remove the error.

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = df[~((df[col].lt(feature_value_less_than_3sigma)) |(df[col].gt (feature_value_greater_than_3sigma)))]
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.